# Sending URL as a parameter using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, urlencode, url-parameters

I have to send a name and a link from client side to the server. I thought of using AJAX called by Javascript to do this.

This is what I mean. I wished to make an ajax request to a file called abc.php with parameters :-

```
1. http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/m7dFgOtLUUUSpktHRspjhXw/140.jpg

2. Apple iPod touch, 3rd generation, 32GB
```

To begin with, I encoded the URL and tried to send it. But the server says status Forbidden

Any solution to this ?

UPDATE ::

It end up calling to

```
http://abc.com/addToWishlist.php?rand=506075547542422&image=http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mO64jQrMqam2jde9aKiXC9A/140.jpg&prod=Flat%20USB%20Data%20Sync%20Charging%20Charger%20Cable%20Apple%20iPhone%204G%204S%20iPod%20Touch%20Nano
```

Javascript Code ::

```
function addToWishlist(num) {
var myurl = "addToWishlist.php";
var myurl1 = myurl;
myRand = parseInt(Math.random()*999999999999999);

var rand  = "?rand="+myRand ;
var modurl = myurl1+ rand + "&image=" + encodeURI(storeArray[num][1]) + "&prod=" + encodeURI(storeArray[num][0]);
httpq2.open("GET", modurl, true);
httpq2.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponseq2;
httpq2.send(null);
}
function useHttpResponseq2() {
if (httpq2.readyState == 4) {
if(httpq2.status == 200) {
var mytext = httpq2.responseText;
document.getElementById('wish' + num).innerHTML = "Added to your wishlist.";
}
}
}
```

Server Code

```
<?php
include('/home/ankit/public_html/connect_db.php');

$image = $_GET['image'];
$prod = $_GET['prod'];
$id = $_GET['id'];



echo $prod;
echo $image;
?>
```

As I mentioned, its pretty basics

More Updates :

On trying to send a POST request via AJAX to the server, it says :-

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length"
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"
```

Comment: Provide some code please

Comment: What url did the AJAX end up calling?

Comment: Is the URL handling your request accessible? It could as well reply 403 to _anything_ regardless of the GET or POST params.

Comment: @JanDvorak If I remove the parameters, they are accessible

Comment: It still looks like a server issue. Can you post the server code?

Comment: @JanDvorak SErver code is just echo of the parameters received

Comment: Did you try intercepting the exact communication with Fiddler or even Wireshark?

Comment: @JanDvorak SOrry, no idea about them. How to use them ?

Comment: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a potent proxy meant for debugging HTTP communication. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) intercepts individual TCP packets including their timing, so you get a _lot_ of information.

Comment: Btw, here is the actual URL, if you can find out something http://comparenext.buyhatke.com/products/addToWishlist.php?rand=506075547542422&image=http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mO64jQrMqam2jde9aKiXC9A/140.jpg&prod=Flat%20USB%20Data%20Sync%20Charging%20Charger%20Cable%20Apple%20iPhone%204G%204S%20iPod%20Touch%20Nano

Comment: Accessing http://comparenext.buyhatke.com/products/addToWishlist.php without the GET parmeters throws a `500 internal server error`.

Comment: It looks like the server does not _just echo_ its get parameters. It probably tries (and fails) to access the URL as well.

Comment: Yeah, it is completely dropping the request

Comment: Please post the server code.

Comment: Added the server side code also in the question

Comment: When I query the exact same query string to my own page, I receive the GET parameters correctly and intact. Anything interesting in `connect_db.php`?

Comment: Also note that your page (comparenext.buyhatke.com) has bad reputation on Web of Trust.

Comment: @JanDvorak That simply contains the connection to database

Comment: @JanDvorak I have updated my question, please have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 things.

1. Use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `encodeURI()`.

   Here is a detailed discussion on this: [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)
2. If you are new to JavaScript, use some lib to help you do the AJAX work. Like mootools, jQuery, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using a POST request solved my issue :)

```
function addToWishlist(num) {
var url = "trial.php";
var parameters = "prod=" + encodeURIComponent(storeArray[num][0]) + "&image=" + encodeURIComponent(storeArray[num][1]);
httpq2.open("POST", url, true);
httpq2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpq2.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (httpq2.readyState == 4) {
if(httpq2.status == 200) {
var mytext = httpq2.responseText;
document.getElementById('wish' + num).innerHTML = "Added to your wishlist.";
}
}
};
httpq2.send(parameters);
}
```